# Tapjoy Property Error?

Tags: xcode, sdk, ads, tapjoy

I am adding Tapjoy SDK code to my app, When I run app,

I get this error code:

```
 property 'showFeaturedBtn' not found on object of type 'UIViewController *'
```

My code I am calling:

```
// Show the custom Tapjoy full screen featured app ad view.
    if (featuredApp)
    {
        [TapjoyConnect showFeaturedAppFullScreenAdWithViewController:mainCtrl_];
        [mainCtrl_.showFeaturedBtn setEnabled:YES];
        [mainCtrl_.showFeaturedBtn setAlpha:1.0f];
    }
}
```

Where it says:

```
[mainCtrl_.showFeaturedBtn setEnabled:YES];
[mainCtrl_.showFeaturedBtn setAlpha:1.0f];
```

I get 2 errors that say:

```
 property 'showFeaturedBtn' not found on object of type 'UIViewController *'
```

Is there a solution?

Answer (score 0):

`showFeaturedBtn`  is something specifically in the Tapjoy sample application and not in the Tapjoy SDK explicitly.  So you can't make reference to it in your application.  This is why you're getting errors.

Comment: Should I delete that code? Please be more specific on what I should do, thanks

Comment: Honestly? Looking at your other answers, buy a book on Objective-C, read it, and come back in 6 months time,